# Blazor Drag and Drop images and Get Sorting Order with js

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, drag, drop

I am Blazor Developer!
Stuck in a problem where I have list of Images and i want to re-order the list through drag and drop Without js and having Virtulization because Images are 1200+,Please check the Images below I want like this ! any idea it can be possbile ?

[image]

Comment: Upload the image to the question instead of inserting a link. It helps make your question understandable.

Comment: What is the point of reordering 1200+ pictures with drag and drop?

Comment: it possible what have you tried ?